# Capsicum potted plants

Tags: containers, capsicum-pubsecens

I want to plant capsicum in a pot.  Is it possible?  If yes is a pot of 5 litres enough?  Also how much  does the plant grow?  Please help.

Comment: capsicum-pubsecens grows up to 7 foot tall, and can live 15 years. You're going to need a much larger pot if you want to keep it for a long time.

Answer (score 4):

A 5 litre pot should be ample.

But not to worry, plants are often sold in plastic pots that are about 10 cm x 10 cm x 10 cm, or even smaller. They possibly will do well in this small space for a  a month or two. One can pop off this pot, loosen the roots on the outside of the soil mass and put it into a larger pot with additional soil. This process can be repeated again and again, in any season, as the pot becomes filled with roots.

The simplest indication that the pot may be saturated with roots is that roots are growing out of the pot's the drainage hole(s). Then one just gently removes the pot. If the exposed soil mass is wrapped in roots, time for a new pot. Else, the pot its in is adequate.