# Size and growth of chilles (repotting needed?)

Tags: repotting

I have chilli plants in 3 pots.  Each pot has about 6-7 plants.  Each pot is about 3 to 5 litres. Is it more than the capacity? Shall i repot them? If I repot them will I get more yield?( now I get about 3-4 chillies every month from each pot) How shall I repot them without damaging the roots? The plants are 1.5 feet.  Will they grow more if I repot them?  Please help.

Comment: I think I answered this with your previous question:

http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23046/capsicum-potted-plants

I think this question is redundant though it differs in some details.

Answer (score 3):

Chillis need a pot size of at least 10 litres. The soil should be heavily organic since they are heavy feeders and ready draining. Smaller pot sizes, assuming non-root pruning pots, cause the chilli to become root bound stressing the plant so that it flowers more readily, but produces a much smaller crop. The added stress might make the plant more susceptible to attack by aphids etc. It also then needs more frequent watering in a small pot and feeding to maintain the crop. Unless you're prepared to lavish all this attention on it, you are better off going for a pot size of at least 20 litres per plant. Depending on where you live you may need to bring them inside for winter as they are highly sensitive to frost, and don't like strong wind.